# WFE server in SharePoint UPDATE REQUIRED

Tags: web-frontend, sharepoint-2016

I just noticed that one of the two web front end is showing "UPDATE REQUIRED"

I looked it up and it talks about taking several steps to upgrade if the update status under "Upgrade and Migration" is failed..... all the status shows "Succeeded" pic shown below for both

So my question is do i need to do something about this "UPDATE REQUIRED" status for the web server since everything under "check upgrade status" as shown above

[image]

[image]